# How to create a new User object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object, handlebars.js

i have this code:

```
//Start of User Constuctor
function User(firstName,lastName){
    this.first = firstName;
    this.last = lastName;
    this.quizScores = [];
    this.currentScore = 0;
}

User.prototype = {
    constructor:User,
    saveScore: function(theScoreToAdd){
        this.quizScores.push(theScoreToAdd)
    },
    showNameAndScores : function(){
        var scores = this.quizScores.length > 0 ? this.quizScores.join(",") : "No  Scores Yet";
        return this.first + " " + this.last + scores;
    }
}

//End of User constructor

//Start of Question Constuctor
function inheritPrototype(childObject, parentObject) {
    // As discussed above, we use the Crockford’s method to copy the properties and methods from the parentObject onto the childObject
    // So the copyOfParent object now has everything the parentObject has
    var copyOfParent = Object.create(parentObject.prototype);

    //Then we set the constructor of this new object to point to the childObject.
    //This step is necessary because the preceding step overwrote the childObject constructor when it overwrote the childObject prototype (during the Object.create() process)
    copyOfParent.constructor = childObject;

    // Then we set the childObject prototype to copyOfParent, so that the childObject can in turn inherit everything from copyOfParent (from parentObject)
    childObject.prototype = copyOfParent;
}

function Question ( question , choices , correctAnswer ){
    //those will be uniqe for every question made
    this.question = question;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
    this.userAnswer = "";

    console.log("created");
}

Question.prototype.getCorrectAnswer = function(){
    return this.correctAnswer;
};

Question.prototype.getUserAnswer = function(){
    return this.userAnswer;
};

Question.prototype.displayQuestion = function(){
    this.question;
    choiceCounter = 0;

    this.choices.forEach(function(eachQuestion){
        choiceCounter;
        eachQuestion;
        choiceCounter ++;
    });

    console.log(this.question);
};

function QuestionCreate( question , choices , correctAnswer ){
    Question.call(this,question,choices,correctAnswer);
};

function UserCreate ( first,last){
    User.call(this,first,last)
}

inheritPrototype(QuestionCreate,Question);

var allQuestions = [
    new QuestionCreate("fist",["1","2","3","4"],1),
    new QuestionCreate("seconed",["1","2","3","4"],2),
    new QuestionCreate("third",["1","2","3","4"],3),
    new QuestionCreate("fourh",["1","2","3","4"],4)
];

allQuestions.forEach(function(eachQuestion){
    eachQuestion.displayQuestion();
});

// End of Question Constuctor

    var allUsers;

if(localStorage["fn"] && localStorage["ln"]){
    $("form").remove();
}

$("#login").bind("click",function(){
    var firstname = $("#fn").val();
    var lastname = $("#ln").val();

    var validfn = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(firstname);// check to match the if the input is a-z char
    var validln = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(lastname);// check to match the if the input is a-z char


    if (validfn && validln) {
        var first = firstname;
        var last = lastname;
        alert(first + " " + last);

        localStorage["fn"] = first;
        localStorage["ln"] = last;

        allUsers = [
            new UserCreate(first, last)
        ]
    }
});
```

As you can see i have a User constuctor.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  <!--manifest="site.manifest" -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <title>Quiz Version 3</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<!-- contaning all display -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- contaning header -- navgiation -->
    <header class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <a href="#" class="brand">Boaz Hoch</a>

                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>

                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav">
                      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="proggres.html">My Proggres</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Follow Me
                          <b class="caret"></b></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/boazmier">FaceBook</a></li>
                              <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/113694258444420573992/posts">Google +</a></li>
                              <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=255626257&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile">Linked-In</a></li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#" class="text-right"></a></li>
                  </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </header>

    <!-- End of Header -->

    <!-- contaning main part -->
    <section class="row" id="main-container">
        <div class="well span6 offset3">
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Login</legend>
                    <input id="fn" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="First Name">
                    <input id="ln" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Last Name">
                    <input id="login" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="login">
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <!-- crappy script tag at the middle of the html file   -->
            <script id="try" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

                <div> My Name is {{this}}</div>

            </script>

        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- contaning all display -->
    <footer class="row">
        <!-- svg
        sqaure
        <svg width="200" height="200">
            <polyline points="20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="none" stroke-width="3"  stroke="red"/>
            <ellipse cx="10" cy="10" rx="10" ry="5"/>
            <line  x1="0" y1="0" x2="5" y2="5" />
        </svg>
        -->

    </footer>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/handlebars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/webapp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/template.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see i have a form, 
now im trying to create a new User (using the consturctur), with the parameters of his first name and last name,
but i cant seem to create it as i want, i just want everytime that a user submit a form to create a new user object.

check my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qMuwe/

Comment: `UserCreate` doesn't return anything, because it has no `return` statement.

Comment: By clicking the submit button you are submitting the form, hence the page is reloading and any javascript object will be deleted.

Comment: @Barmar you dont need the return.  Please remove the  `$("form").remove();`
 from your fiddle.

Comment: updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qMuwe/1/

Comment: @בועזהוך, you are creating 2 values in `localstorage` and overwriting them each time the form is submitted. The `allUsers` object dies milliseconds after its creation, when the form is submitted. JS does not survive page reloads. Can you explain your desired scenario? Did you consider using AJAX for the form submission?

Comment: yes i have consider ajax, but i m trying to avoid ajax call. the thing is i want the user, to enter a vlaue to first name and last name and saves those values to localstorage, and then after the page reloads there will be welcome message + user first name + user last name

Comment: Do you have a back-end framework supporting this page?

Comment: no, im not using any back-end here. im trying to create a little quiz web app using only client side (javascripit,jquery,handlebars.js).

Comment: OK. The submission simply reloads the page with the `fn`, `ln` variables set up. I would construct this a bit differently: I would check for the names in localStorage. If they are found, I would construct the quiz page as normal. If not, I would create the form and execute the rest of the initialization process once it is submitted (without reloading the page).

Comment: ok ,you think AJAX call is more appropriate here?

Comment: Since there is no back-end, no need for any call. You should simply capture the input, remove the form and go on with the construction of the quiz.